# a method about array algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

```
class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;
}

    private static Node GenerateList(params int[] array) {
        Node node = null;
        for (int i = a.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            node = new Node { value = array[i], next = node }; 
        }
        return node;
    }
```

This `GenerateList` method makes a list from an array, but I can not understand `node = new Node { value = array[i], next = node };`.

Fir example, in the first loop: node is equal to a new node, but new node's next node points to the older node. In the second loop, the second new node is equal to the first node, the second new node's node will point to the first node, but what will happen to second node?

What am I not understanding?

Comment: "a method about array algorithm" doesn't seem to be a summary of your question. Please try again, and write a title that conforms to the guidelines set out in [ask].

Comment: Try running the expanded https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYzoByA9sAKb6HFroCWAdgC7oBuAhgDYCu1ANz0ijSjXQtqADzYikAX2Sj0ABwBOTHm1pQ4ANnJVaAcWrSN3XQBkmAZzYAKNdysBbe83YBtALroblYAngCUdEjEUcaSLCboALxS/Ly8CtHEAGYUGuhOrBxMiYEaIQB0NhYA5mwAFugAtOhwQszoAHxJAAytTA0N4XjoqhlEcZJJ0gDuMbRDPAK0SUHcwT5MfgA0UrIck/GKrSPEypGjUADsUibpJ8iKQA=== version with the the line by line debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022 (other IDE have similar features)

Comment: hmm, have you got constructor ?. I think this need a constructor, some thing like this :

Comment: public Node(int value, Node next)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an `array` to the `link list` algorithm.

input: array

output: link list

The starting node is set with the last element of the array. The `next` is set with the nearest item in the array that will be set in the next iteration of the loop. in each step, you move backwards in the array till the start of the array.

This example can help:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain but not sure that is what you looking for.

It seems like it convert Array to LinkList and more specifically Queue.

Now if you look at the for loop carefully then it is in reverse order.

1. At first iteration node = null. At that time it will get last element from array and create node and assign next to null. This process assign new reference to node variable.
2. Now for second iteration , it will assign second last value from array to node value and at that time it will assign previously create node as next.

This will it will reach to first value and node.

From if you have just reference of node and if you start looking for next node is there or not then it will go upto last value of array.